# Clarification for Secret warehouse

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-cities

Scenario. 
Alice has played in previous turns the following cards:

- Timber yard (brown card) - gives 1 resource: stone **OR** wood.
- Secret Warehouse (black card)

From the rule book for Secret Warehouse:

> Each turn, the card produces a resource of the
>   player’s choice from among those that their
>   city already produces through its brown and
>   gray cards or the initial resource of their board.
>   Clarification : the Secret Warehouse doesn’t
>   allow players to double the production on yellow,
>   white, or black cards (Forum, Caravansary,
>   Bilkis and Black Market).

Alice has not played any other card that produces stone or wood.

**Question**
Can Alice use one stone **AND** one wood to play a card that requires both?

**Additional info:**
In our "7-wonders group" we don't allow this since we kind of assume that the secret warehouse "doubles" a resource as its symbol suggests. So we interpreted it as "You pick either stone or wood and you can use 2 of them".
But the [mobile game app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rprod.sevenwonders&hl=en) allows the use of one stone **AND** one wood.
I'm asking here because I don't trust how the rules are implemented in the mobile app since I found other bugs / inconsistencies in it in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, she can.**

The game's creator weighs in a few posts down at [this BGG thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/850432/question-about-secret-warehouse-and-age-i-double-r/page/2)

> Secret Warehouse & Black Market depend of your resource icons present
>   on your "board"
>
> So if you have a STONE or CLAY brown card (and nothing else) :
>
> - SW can produce either a STONE or a CLAY
> - BM can't produce neither a Stone or a CLAY (none of them)
>
> SW & BM don't depend on the use you make of the resources on turn T,
>   it depend on what resource are present on your brown cards.